# How to set the requested presence with Telepathy-Glib-GJS?

Tags: gnome, gjs

According to the [Telepathy Developer's Manual](http://telepathy.freedesktop.org/doc/book/sect.connection.obtaining.html):
"To bring an account online, set RequestedPresence to an online state[..]"

For [TelepathyGlib.Account](https://people.gnome.org/~gcampagna/docs/TelepathyGLib-0.12/TelepathyGLib.Account.html) under GJS I can see a TelepathyGLib.Account.prototype.get_requested_presence but not an equivalent setter. What's the right way to bring a telepathy account online in GJS/TelepathyGlib?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not immediately obvious, but you don't set a presence, you [request](http://telepathy.freedesktop.org/doc/telepathy-glib/telepathy-glib-account.html#tp-account-request-presence-async) it ...